# NullValueHandling.Ignore influences deserialization into [ExtensionData] despite matching class member

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

My server responses consists of a set of known and unknown properties. For the known ones, I created a DTO class with members for each property. The unknown properties shall be put inside a dictionary annotated with the `[ExtensionData]` attribute:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Dto
{

    [JsonExtensionData]
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> unknownProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public IDictionary<string, object> UnknownProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>(this.unknownProperties);
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default, PropertyName = "KNOWN_PROPERTY")]
    public string KnownProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

`Null` is allowed as value for `KnownProperty`. If I try to deserialize a JSON object that contains `KNOWN_PROPERTY : null`, this property is also contained in the dictionary `UnknownProperties`, if I configure the serializer with `NullValueHandling.Ignore`. This is done even though a class member exists for `KNOWN_PROPERTY`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string jsonString = @"{
          KNOWN_PROPERTY : null,
          UNKNOWN_PROPERTY : null
   }";

   JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings()
   {
       NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    });

    using (var textReader = new StringReader(jsonString))
    {
       Dto dto = serializer.Deserialize<Dto>(new JsonTextReader(textReader));
       foreach (var pair in dto.UnknownProperties)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value == null ? "null" : pair.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
 }
```

Output:

```
 KNOWN_PROPERTY : null
 UNKNOWN_PROPERTY : null
```

If I configure the serializer with `NullValueHandling.Include` or set a value for `KNOWN_PROPERTY` in the JSON string, the dictionary contains only `UNKNOWN_PROPERTY`, as expected.

For my understanding `[ExtensionData]` is not working correctly if `NullValueHandling` is set to ignore, since the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm) states the extension is used only if no matching class member is found.

Is the behavior I'm seeing intended? Can I do something to avoid this? Because I don't like to send null values to the server, I'd like to stick to the currently set `NullValueHandling`.

I'm using Json.NET 8.0.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Reported in [JsonExtensionData should not include the null values that are real object properties. #1719](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1719) and fixed in commit [e079301](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/e079301905988f1d78702cbd8e7d90a39aaf7c26).  The fix should be included in the next release of Json.NET after 11.0.2.

**Original Answer**

Confirmed - in [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(object, JsonReader, JsonObjectContract, JsonProperty, string)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs) there is the following logic:

```
// set extension data if property is ignored or readonly
if (!SetPropertyValue(property, propertyConverter, contract, member, reader, newObject))
{
    SetExtensionData(contract, member, reader, memberName, newObject);
}
```

The intent seems to be to put the value into the extension data if the *property* is to be ignored, but Json.NET puts it into the extension data if the *value* is to be ignored -- a slightly different concept.  I agree this could be a bug.  You might want to [report it](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues).

There is a workaround.  Json.NET has *two* attributes that affect how null/default values are serialized:

- [`NullValueHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm).  Specifies to include or ignore null values when serializing and deserializing objects.   Values are `Include` and `Ignore`.
- [`DefaultValueHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm).  This has more elaborate semantics:

  1. `Include`: Include members where the member value is the same as the member's default value when serializing objects. Included members are written to JSON. Has no effect when deserializing.
  2. `Ignore`: Ignore members where the member value is the same as the member's default value when serializing objects so that is is not written to JSON. This option will ignore all default values (e.g. null for objects and nullable types; 0 for integers, decimals and floating point numbers; and false for booleans).
  3. `Populate`: Members with a default value but no JSON will be set to their default value when deserializing.
  4. `IgnoreAndPopulate`: Ignore members where the member value is the same as the member's default value when serializing objects and sets members to their default value when deserializing.

So, how do these overlapping settings interact?  It turns out that Json.NET checks them both: serialize if both settings are agreeable, deserialize if both settings are agreeable.  And `DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate` appears to do what you want -- it omits nulls when serializing, but reads and sets them when deserializing, if present.

Thus I was able to get your desired behavior with the following `JsonProperty`:

```
public class Dto
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default, PropertyName = "KNOWN_PROPERTY", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
    public string KnownProperty { get; private set; }

    // Remainder as before.
}
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C7hE3J).